# Generators for $M_n(\mathbb Q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra

What is the minimum number of generators for $M_n(\mathbb Q)$, the set of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb Q$, which will generate it as an algebra over $\mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: @Valeriya: Wow, five questions in half an hour! Take a breath!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an exercise from Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I* which says that the answer is 2. It's from the exercises in section 7.1 (page 410 in the second edition, page 391 in the first edition).

[image]

Comment: For me an easier generating set is E11 and the n-cycle permutation matrix P=A+E(n,1). { P^i*E11*P^j } = { Eij }, though the indexing looks better with 0-based matrices, I think.